# Show yup field validation when other fields are empty. At least one field has to be valid

Tags: reactjs, yup

i need to show validation error when atleast one of the 5 checkboxes is not selected using yup form.
i tried by creating schema in this way

```
const accumulatorsSchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required("Name is required"),
  a: yup.string(),
  b: yup.string(),
  c: yup.string(),
  d: yup.string(),
  e: yup.string(),
  checkbox_selection: yup.string().when(["a","b", "c","d", "e"], {
    is: (a, b, c, d, e) => !a && !b && !c && !d && !e,
    then: yup.string().required("At least one checkbox is to be selected"),
    otherwise: yup.string()
  })
})
```

here in the above code a,b,c,d,e are five checkboxes where i am going to save "Y" on checked and "N" on unchecked. if atleast one of them is not checked then i need to show a required validation error. i couldn't find a way to fix it. can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tested your schema, it works, logic is fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/yup-playground-forked-krlqy?file=/src/index.js
Recreate the problem in codesandbox and share it so we can debug the problem.

Comment: @FilipSeman, Thanks for helping me out. After seeing your comment i have gone through my code thoroughly and i have found the issue and fixed it. Value is not being set properly after the checkbox is checked. Thats the issue.

Comment: Yes, as I thought, the reproduced link I provided passed the verification and failed on the empty objects of the `{a...e}` scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your schema, it works, the logic is fine.

**Reproduced**

[codesandbox.io/s/yup-playground-forked-krlqy?file=/src/index.js](http://codesandbox.io/s/yup-playground-forked-krlqy?file=/src/index.js)

```js
import { object, string } from "yup";

const schema = object().shape({
    name: string().required("Name is required"),
    a: string(),
    b: string(),
    c: string(),
    d: string(),
    e: string(),
    checkbox_selection: string().when(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], {
        is: (a, b, c, d, e) => !a && !b && !c && !d && !e,
        then: string().required("At least one checkbox is to be selected"),
        otherwise: string() // unnecessary
    })
});

schema
    // .validate({ name: "foo" })         // ValidationError: At least one checkbox is to be selected
    .validate({ name: "foo", a: 'foo' })  // Ok
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```